# File restrictions in android Nougat

Tags: android

I am getting image from gallery / capture with camera. then i want to resize the image if needed and save it to the same location.
To do so i use the following code:

```
File file = new File(photoLocation);
file.setWritable(true);
try {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }else{
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    }
```

Sadly I get

> FileNotFound error (permission denied)

I tried the same code on Android 4 device and it works ok so I assume it's because of the file access restrictions in android 7.
How can I write to file now?

Also the error:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/3061-6133/DCIM/Camera/20161213_081733.jpg (Permission denied)
>   12-22 23:55:00.269 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:221) 12-22
>   23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers W/System.err:
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:169) 12-22
>   23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers.ProductActivity$BitmapGetter.doInBackground(ProductActivity.java:465)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers.ProductActivity$BitmapGetter.doInBackground(ProductActivity.java:410)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 12-22
>   23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 12-22
>   23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   12-22 23:55:00.270 28524-28736/com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: Where exactly is `file` pointing to? IOW, what is the value of `photoLocation`?

Comment: @CommonsWare my bad forgot to add the error, I eddited the post with the error (location is in the error first line)

Comment: I do not know how you got that path (`/storage/3061-6133/DCIM/Camera/20161213_081733.jpg`). That looks to be on removable storage, and [you have neither read nor write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage, starting with Android 4.4](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare well I open gallery using StartActivityForResault() and pick image, I then use the data.getData() to get the url and a cursor to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

> I open gallery using StartActivityForResault() and pick image, I then use the data.getData() to get the url and a cursor to get the path.

Get rid of the "and a cursor to get the path" part. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` and `openOutputStream()` to work with the content identified by the `Uri`. Your `bitmap.compress()` call would work with the `OutputStream` from `openOutputStream()`, for example.

Comment: I need to use cursor to get path so i will be able to use ExifInterface.

Comment: BTW I just ended up creating a new file instead trying to modify the one the use picked. (I did used openOutPutSteam() to write to this file so thanks for your help)

Comment: @yotamhadas: "I need to use cursor to get path so i will be able to use ExifInterface" -- not if you use a better `ExifInterface`, such as [the one just added to the support library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html). The one that you are using [has security flaws](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/08/dealing-exifinterface-security-flaw.html).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to press shift+enter, THIS IS AWESOME!
I dont read throuly this new patch notes as I still learning the basic but its awesome library, thank you for sharing!